# How do you specify the version of azure-functions-core-tools?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-functions-core-tools

I have an AzureDevOps pipeline which was running fine a few weeks ago. When I tried to run it again, I got an error which apparently is caused by running the latest `azure-functions-core-tools`. It was suggested to downgrade it but I couldn't find how to do it on Azure CLI.

I tried adding the version to the code below but it didn't work.

```
sudo apt-get install azure-functions-core-tools=(version I want to use)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ I don't know anything about Azure but I found this DevOps document that includes comments below the article where Azure's 'Principal Program Manager' appears to acknowledge that 'downgrading' is not possible but that a patch to cover this will be released sometime in November _ I hope it helps >>> https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/september-patches-for-azure-devops-server-and-team-foundation-server/

Comment: Firstly `apt-cache showpkg <azure-functions-core-tools>` list available package then you could try `sudo aptitude install <azure-functions-core-tools>=<version>`.

Comment: @George Chen You can convert your comment into an answer.

Comment: @formerdev could you downgrade it now?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly use `apt-cache showpkg <package-name>` to list available versions.

Then use `sudo aptitude install <azure-functions-core-tools>=<version>`  to install the version.